# SupportActionBar composite background image

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-actionbar-compat, android-actionbaractivity

I want to style my application action bar like the following

[image: Action Bar prototype]

The basic background color is **green**

**Centered** image with a **fixed width** (ex: 250dp)

I have a **button** (three horizontal lines) that i use to open another interface

How can i achieve this ? (xml or programmaticly)

**PS** : i am using SupportActionBar (android.support.v7.app.ActionBar)

Thanks

Comment: i have edited my answer you can set image background and image background color simply in layout.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/ is a very usefull approach to style the action bar.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but this is far away of what i need. I already saw this styling generator. There is no "image" background included